# What do the square brackets mean, when it is after a string, and not an array?

Tags: c#

What do the square brackets mean, when it is after a string, and not an array? (e.g. str[5] in the following example)

```
string str;
Console.Write("Input a string : ");
str = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(
    (str.Length < 6 && str.Equals("Hello")) 
    || (str.StartsWith("Hello") && str[5] == ' ')
);
```

Comment: A string is an array.  Of characters.

Comment: Sorry I am new, and re editted it. Could you look at it again?

Comment: @Ingino - David has given you the answer. A string can be perceived as an array of characters (i.e. a char[]) thus you can index it: `char sixthChar = str[5];`

Answer (score 2):

It treats a string as an array, so `str[5]` is the 6th (it is base zero) element of the string.

Edit:  A bit more detail:

```
 Console.WriteLine((str.Length < 6 && str.Equals("Hello")) || (str.StartsWith("Hello") && str[5] == ' '));
```

This is a bit redundant:

```
(str.Length < 6 && str.Equals("Hello")
```

It is a check that the input string is both less than 6 Characters long, and it is exactly equal (case sensitive) to "Hello".  It could be simplified to

```
str.Equals("Hello")
```

This is the array bit:

```
(str.StartsWith("Hello") && str[5] == ' ')
```

It is a check to see if the string starts with "Hello" (fairly self explanatory), but then the next bit checks if the next character is a space (' ').

Overall, it will print **TRUE** if the input string is 'Hello' or 'Hello ', and **FALSE** otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing it means anywhere else.  A string *is* an array (or at least has an indexer)... of `char`s.

For example, say you have a string:

```
var x = "Hello, Cruel World."
```

Then you can index it to get a `char`:

```
var y = x[1];
```

At that point `y` is now the character `'e'`.